# Elements with nowrap get stuck to adjacent elements in WebKit

Tags: html, css, nowrap

I have a `ul` list that I display as a horizontal menu. I'd like the content of each `li` to remain on one line, but the entire `li` items to jump lines as necessary. Something like:

`First entry in the menu`  `Second menu entry`
`These words are short, the LI jumps lines, but doesn't wrap`
`Yet anoter]` `[And more]` `[Some more]`

Logically, I'd just put `li {white-space:nowrap;}`, but there is a problem with WebKit browsers. **Items with nowrap get stuck to adjacent items.** So in the case above, all the `li` will be on the same line.

The same goes for an isolated element with `nowrap` inside a wrapping text block.

```
<p>Visit my sites <a href="http://gabrielradic.com/" style="white-space:nowrap">Gabriel Radic
.com (English)</a> or <a href="http://www.timbru.com/" style="white-space:nowrap">Timbru Blog
(Romanian)</a>.
```

What I would expect is something like:

*Visit my sites **Gabriel Radic .com** or

**Timbru Blog***

Instead, the two links end up stuck together, like:

*Visit my sites

**Gabriel Radic .com** or **Timbru Blog (Romanian)***

Is there a nice way to tell Safari, Chrome and others to stop grabbing people's elbows?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of using `white-space:nowrap`, in this case it's more appropriate to go with `display:inline-block`.**

The CSS needs to be adapted here and there for the change, but it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want the text inside the list items to wrap, but not the menu itself, is that right? so that it looks something like:

```
item one | item two | item number | item four 
                         three
```

But not have it look like:

```
item one | item two | item number three | 
item four
```

If that's the case, have you tried setting the `nowrap` on the actual `ul` instead of on the list items, since it's the `ul` that you are trying to make not wrap? Then set a width for the list items so that they will wrap to fit that width.

Comment: Actually, I need the LIs or the As from my examples to always be on the same line, but the whole item may jump to another line if necessary. I want them to behave like ... (wait for it) ... _inline blocks_. Which seems to be the answer I was looking for :-)